# How to loop over a $_SESSION and print the values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have created three files and in one of them i would like to make a loop over a Section to output the name and the price from my array

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
<?php 
  $a=array(
      array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Milch','price'=>'12'),
      array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Reis','price'=>'13'),
      array('id'=>'3','name'=> 'Öl', 'price'=>'14'),
      array('id'=>'4','name'=>'Salz','price'=>'15'),
      array('id'=>'5','name'=>'Zucker','price'=>'16'),      
        );       
if(empty($_SESSION['warenkorb'])){       
   echo 'Warenkorb leer';
   }           
else {                          
   foreach($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $key=>$value){ 
   $_SESSION['warenkorb']=array();            
   print_r($value['name'].': '.'$'.$value['price'].PHP_EOL.'<br />');
     }
   }                                      
  ?>
```

And this is another file with a lesson that i output from it only the id

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
 ?php         
     include 'produkte.php';           
     if(!isset($_SESSION['warenkorb'])){  
       $_SESSION['warenkorb']=array();
         }                                
        if(isset($_POST['id'])){             
        foreach($a as $key =>$value){  
        if($value['id']==$_POST['id']){                     
           $_SESSION['warenkorb'][]= $_POST['id'];              
          }              
         }
        }     
        print_r(count($_SESSION['warenkorb']));          
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first code you need to change some bit in the ***else*** part:-

```
else {                          
    foreach($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $key=>$value){  //iterate over SESSION array
        foreach($a as $v){ //iterate over $a array
            if($value == $v['id']){ //compare SESSION is with $a sub-array id         
                echo $v['name'].': '.'$'.$v['price'].'<br />'; // if match then echo name and price from sub-array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

just use
`echo "<pre>"`
`print_r($_SESSION)`
 to print all key values inside `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: this is the output that i get:
 Array ( [warenkorb] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [warenkorb] => Array ( ) )

Comment: @ALQAM this means you don't have any values associated with 'warenkrob' key in SESSION array

Comment: you could check if the array has any values in it with $_SESSION['warenkorb'].length

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I interpreted right, I tried the most literal interpretation of your question's title

```
<?php 
$a = array(
    array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Milch','price'=>'12'),
    array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Reis','price'=>'13'),
    array('id'=>'3','name'=> 'Öl', 'price'=>'14'),
    array('id'=>'4','name'=>'Salz','price'=>'15'),
    array('id'=>'5','name'=>'Zucker','price'=>'16'),
);
```

You now have an array named `$a` containing all your names and prices.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['warenkorb'])) {
    echo 'Warenkorb leer';
} else {
    foreach ($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $key => $value) {
```

You iterate on `$_SESSION['warenkorb']`. Which each iteration, `$key` and `$value` are set with the key and value of another entry from `$_SESSION['warenkorb']`.

```
        $_SESSION['warenkorb'] = array();
```

Yet, the first thing your code do during the first looping is to reset `$_SESSION['warenkorb']` as an empty array.

```
        print_r($value['name'].': '.'$'.$value['price'].PHP_EOL.'<br />');
```

Since you have reset the same array you are iterating over, this line will never be executed again, first and last time it is. Yet, it still does nothing because the entries you are trying to print are in `$a`.

```
    }
}
?>
```

Try this:

```
<?php 
$_SESSION['warenkorb'] = array(
    array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Milch','price'=>'12'),
    array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Reis','price'=>'13'),
    array('id'=>'3','name'=> 'Öl', 'price'=>'14'),
    array('id'=>'4','name'=>'Salz','price'=>'15'),
    array('id'=>'5','name'=>'Zucker','price'=>'16'),
);
if (empty($_SESSION['warenkorb'])) {
    echo 'Warenkorb leer';
} else {
    foreach ($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value['name'].': '.'$'.$value['price'].PHP_EOL.'<br />');
    }
}
?>
```